# How to get the Foreign keys belong to a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have q query to list out the columns in a table as follows

`select name from sys.all_columns as AllCols where object_id=xxxxxx`

I would like to display the columns except the  `foriegn key` columns is there any way to filter with the above query so that it should display all columns except foreign key columns

Comment: This may help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807%28v=sql.100%29.aspx (sys.foreign_keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by quering sys.sysforeignkeys and then removing the results from the 'AllCols' query by using EXCEPT operator.

```
DECLARE @objectid INT = object_id('Schema.TableName')

SELECT name  FROM sys.all_columns as AllCols
WHERE object_id=@Objectid
EXCEPT
SELECT name  FROM sys.all_columns as AllCols
INNER JOIN sys.sysforeignkeys AS AllFks
ONAllCols.column_id = AllFks.fkey or AllCols.column_id = AllFks.rkey
WHERE object_id=@Objectid
```

Comment: What is the issue you got? Notice there is a space missing in 7th line "ONAllCols" -> "ON AllCols"